# I did object detection using yolo-v4 which detects only on one camera. but now i need to use 50-cam at the same time for object-detection. how to do?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, python-multiprocessing, yolov4

python yolo v4 algo for object detection

assume I have 50 cameras, I need to do object detection in all 50 cameras. It shouldn't run in series. all 50 should run in parallel. how to do this. for Realtime purpose. I tried multithreading and processing but I am very very bad at it. I am complete beginner to python and this seems very hard for me.

I know none of us have 50 camera to check so I created a path variable where location of 50 images are specified. just need to run 50 images in parallel for object detection

````
import os, time
import cv2

coco_classes = ["car", "plate", "motorcycle"]

net = cv2.dnn.readNet("custom.weights", "custom.cfg")
model = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(net)
model.setInputParams(size=(416, 416), scale=1 / 255, swapRB=True)

path = './img/'

for fn in os.listdir(path):
    image = cv2.imread(path + fn)

    t = time.time()
    c, v, b = model.detect(image, 0.2, 0.4)
    t = time.time() - t

    c = [coco_classes[x] for x in c]
    print('{}ms : '.format(int(t * 1000)), list(zip(c, v)))```
````

Comment: Have you done the math on this to see if it can keep up?  If you have 8 cores in your computer, you can only do 8 at a time.  It's going to take 6 times as long as doing 1.  How do you plan to read from 50 cameras, and what kind of cameras?  You can't hook 50 USB cameras to one system.

Comment: Best would be to run 50 applications in parallel, but you will need a very very very strong device.

Comment: @TimRoberts see that i am not connecting any cameras directly to my system. all the frames from each camera are stored in a cloud storage. i have access to a .jpg link which contains the recent image from that particular camera. each cam has its own .jpg URL which i will use to download image from all 50 cams. now i just need to run the 50 images for object detection to reduce the time consumed. multiprocessing is not a solution but it's acceptable if i can get a working code, i need to know what i should do to run this in parallel or concurrent.

Comment: @Micka have you ever done any object detection before.

Comment: If you have a tool to handle one image, why not just start 50 of those?  Why worry about using Python multiprocessing?

Comment: @TimRoberts bro, I have to run them in parallel. are you understanding me. it take 1.5 second to do object detection. that's not the only thing i am doing. i have other tasks after object detection. in total it takes 4 seconds for one image. its not good to run in series since 4*50 seconds is not practical for REAL TIME APPLICATION. this programme will run all day all night all year without stopping.

Comment: And do you understand that, if you have 8 cores in your computer, it's going to take 4 x 50 / 8 or 25 seconds to process one round?  You'll get 2 frames per minute.  You could do this by starting a `multiprocessing.Pool`, and assigning each one a URL.

Comment: Let's say you had a script that processed one camera continuously, in an infinite loop, given the URL as a command line parameter.  Now let's say you had a shell script that started 50 copies of that script, each one with it's own URL.  That would solve the problem without requiring Python multiprocessing.

Comment: @ModelTrainer yes I've trained and used DNN models and other techniques for object detection over the last 15 years. If the 50 cameras work independently, the smoothest and clearest way is to run each of the camera with another instance of your application. If you really have to use them together in one application (e.g. to fuse the results together) you will need a good framework and/or multithreading experience. BUT: since already a single yolo v4 is vry expnsive and will probably consume most of your processing hardware, you will need a good hardware strategy for 50 parallel runs either way

Comment: One benefit of processing N cameras in a single application could be to spare some memory for holding the DNN, but you will introduce additional latency when camera pipelines have to wait for the DNN which is in use by another camera. The OS/driver schedulers for both, CPU and GPU are probably smarter/better than your own in-application ones.

Comment: @TimRoberts YES. i understand it. thanks for explaining it. i didn't try using multiprocessing pool. i did try using multithreading pool. and can you like tell me about the shell script and how to do it so that it can start running 50 images like you said. any sample code which i can refer. what should i be googling

Comment: @Micka what is this 'run each of the camera with another instance of your application. ' and what it means. how to do it. got any sample code which i could refer to achieve this.

Comment: @Micka is there a way to contact you. like you mentioned 'you will need a good framework and/or multithreading experience' and I have 0 experience. would you be kind enough to help me get through this task

Comment: @ModelTrainer just image if you want to compress 2 different files in 2 different .zip files run start 7zip application twice, which then perform the compression task in parallel. Just do it the same way. implement an application that gets the camera as input parameter and then run that application once with the first camera and then, while it is running, start the application with the second camera. Then they will both run in parallel. Do the same with all 50 cameras and 50 applications. BUT your system will probably too slow (and it's the very same with a single app and multi-threading).

Comment: @Micka so assume the real time application where my customer has n car parking spots and each spot has a camera allocated. and using those cams i need to check if a car parking spot is free or occupied. assuming this as the situation and no other solution. in real time we need live updates of these information so best would be to run the code in parallel. what would you do with the yolo algorithm above. would you use shell script and run all 50 in 50 instances or do multiprocessing.pool.

Comment: first you should check how many cameras you can process in the needed time. For example if you need an update per parking spot every 10 seconds and your systems only can process 2.5 cameras (rounded down: M = 2) in those 10 seconds, you then will know how many processing devices you will need (50/M). Then on each device run M instances in parallel.